# How to make objects uploaded to S3 bucket readable without explicitly setting their permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I want to make objects uploaded to S3 bucket readable without explicitly setting their permissions.

Relevant discussion I found about Digital Ocean S3 is [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-set-permission-of-all-files-in-a-bucket-as-public-on-every-upload).

As in the above and other discussions, I was able to find solutions to set permissions **only when you upload the files**.

In my scenario, image files are uploaded every minute by a bunch of webcams with proprietary software, so I cannot manage the way permissions are set.

How could I update my `bucket/image.jpg` permissions to READ in bulk, regularly, let's say every 10 minutes?

I need a Cloud Storage to store a very large images database as well as having each image readble by a script in order to be shown into a web interface.

So far I considered scheduling command line tasks on S3 Browser software, but [it seems that only upload, download and sync are allowed commands](https://s3browser.com/s3cmd.aspx).

Is there a way using S3 API I missed, or could you suggest using a different approach from S3 Cloud Object Storage? 
All suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: *"In my scenario, image files are uploaded every minute by a bunch of webcams with proprietary software"* ... and this proprietary software knows how to store images directly in Amazon S3 but not how to set object ACLs?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution is to create a **[Bucket Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html)** that grants `s3:GetObject` to all images in your upload folder.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",           ## This grants public access - update to your needs 
      "Action": [
         "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name/some-folder/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

This way an implicit `s3:GetObject` policy will be applied to your images in `s3://your-bucket-name/some-folder/*` and they should be accessible by you consumers.

However note that the above policy makes the images *publicly readable* which may not be what you want. I suggest at least restricting the read access by client IP address through a `Condition` which can be part of the above policy.

Hope that helps :)